# How to add non-latin entries in hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts, unicode

Is there a way to add non-latin entries in /etc/hosts on windows?

Something like

```
127.0.0.1   локалхост
```

Tried the code above and also punycode with no luck

Yes, i know that this would break almost any app and wouldn't pass any validation. I only need to pull this off for a single machine.

Answer (score 13):

Scratch that, punycodes actually do work. This code

```
127.0.0.1 xn--80atccmdviy
```

works as expected, it's just that ping for some reason won't find host, probably due to cmd working in CP-1251 instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to use Unicode characters in the windows hosts file

Comment: This is correct. Most subsystems have never seen any meaningful upgrades after they were introduced, especially the system ones.